# Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM7505 won't connect to laptop via USB

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I am using Note 3 but I'm unable to connect my phone to PC or laptop. MTP or USB bar option did not pop up when I connected my phone. Please help.

Comment: Usual first-aids include: using a different cable, plugging into a different port on the PC; check on the PC whether the device was detected at all. Have you done that?

Comment: DIDN'T WORK FOR ME.

Comment: Insufficient data for more recommendations. Please [edit] your question and include what OS you are using on PC/Laptop, whether the device is detected there at all (device manager on Windows, `lsusb` on Linux).